# Is it possible to record a 4K time-lapse on iPhone?

Tags: ios, camera

In iOS 8 Apple released a time-lapse feature for the camera app. It seems as though time-lapses are recorded in 1080p. I would like the time-lapse to be recorded instead in 4K. Is this possible?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No, the default camera app does not record time lapse in 4K unfortunately. I believe that there are third-party apps that will work. Alternatively you can just record a 4K video (set it to the lowest frame rate in settings) and then speed it up in iMovie on your phone. You might have to speed up>export>import>speed up a couple times to get it to be quick enough.